# How do i get d3-cloud to work in vue with node?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, canvas, d3-cloud

I am trying to use this example to get a basic word cloud to draw. I am using Vue 3 and node v16.19.0.

I want the word cloud to draw inside of a div container but I'm quite new to d3 and never used d3-cloud.

This is where the code is from https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/node.js

```
import { createCanvas } from 'canvas'
import * as cloud from 'd3-cloud'

const words = ["Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words", "than", "this"]
    .map(function(d) {
      return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
    });

cloud().size([960, 500])
    .canvas(() => createCanvas(1, 1))
    .words(words)
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 90)
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(d => d.size)
    .on("end", words => console.log(JSON.stringify(words)))
    .start();
```

I have tried putting the code under the imports inside a draw function that runs on mounted and the code runs with no errors but I'm not seeing anything appear. I'm guessing this is because I haven't provided it with a container to draw the cloud but I'm not too sure how to do that.